# 'Please wait' popup box and populate another field on selection of drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have something like this. I'm using php as server side language. Basically, I have a form with two drop down boxes. Once I've selected the value for the first drop down list, I want a 'Please wait' box to appear on screen and then it should populate the values for the next drop down list before the popup disappears. I know Jquery is needed but I've never used it before.

```
     <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_16"     name="q16_paymentMode">      /////////select from this list
            <option onclick="" value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option onclick="" value="2"> 2 </option>   
            </select>

     <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:150px" id="input_17" name="q17_paymentMode">    ///////////populate selection list for this field 
            <? php echo '<option value="foobar">foobar</option>'    ?> 

          </select>
```

Comment: You can use good old javascript if you don't want to include jquery.  Do you have code that you've tried?

Comment: So you know jquery is needed, but you don't want to learn ? http://learn.jquery.com/ ? If your data is in server side : Ajax http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @Jahnux73 jQuery is not **needed**

Comment: @RoryPicko92 ps: it's an extract from 'his' question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple!

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#first_dropdown').change(function() {
        $('#please-wait-box').show();
        $.get('url-to-your-resource', {param: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
                if (data) {
                        // populate second drop down here with the receive data
                        // you can do that with old javascript or still with jquery
                }
                $('#please-wait-box').hide();
        });
    });

});
```

There are lots of ways to do that, this is one way and not very recommended if you need that for more than one dropdown, but works or gives you an idea.

Sorry for my english, hope this helps!